# Writing a JerseyTest for an external tomcat server

Tags: java, unit-testing, rest, tomcat, jersey

I am currently attempting to write some unit tests for a REST API written using Jersey. I saw a quite nice [tutorial](http://www.hascode.com/2011/09/rest-assured-vs-jersey-test-framework-testing-your-restful-web-services/) which however unfortunately deals with Jersey version 1.9 and not the current version 2.15. Unfortunately the [migration guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/migration.html) does not seem to adress the problems I am experiencing. I am attempting to setup an external test:

```
@Override
protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
    return new ExternalTestContainerFactory();
}
```

The problem is that I need to implement the `configure()` method. Currently my attempt looks like this:

```
@Override
protected Application configure() {
    return new ResourceConfig(SomeResource.class);
}
```

The problem seems to be that the `client()` method returns `null`, so I can't create any `target()` requests to test anything. Unfortunately the examples which I found all deal with Jersey version 1.x and do not seem to be applicable to my situation. Could anyone tell me what is going wrong or provide me with a code sample of a working test?!

Comment: Why did the people change the API anyways? Using version 1 it was as simple as `WebResource webResource = client().resource("http://localhost:8080/");`. Right now REST-assured looks a lot nicer and simpler to me...

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366692/how-to-specify-context-path-for-jersey-test-with-external-provider