# REST WEB SERVICE URI

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am developing one REST web service project using jersey. I have deployed my project in Tomcat and my project works well.
I am calling my REST web service by following URL:

> http://localhost:8080/MYRESTPROJ/rest/test?name=sachin

But i want to call my REST Web service without using context path in my URL.
i want to call like this

> http://localhost:8080/rest/test?name=sachin

removed MYRESTPROJ(contextpath)
Is that possible to call my REST web service without contextPath?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Check if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366692/how-to-specify-context-path-for-jersey-test-with-external-provider

Comment: Thanks for you reply pringi.. But It seems the above link is related to jersey test. I am not sure whether it is related to my question or not.Still didn't get any idea.

Comment: You have to deploy your application at the root of tomcat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328518/deploying-my-application-at-the-root-in-tomcat

Comment: @pedrofb - Got the solution from the link you shared..Thanks..